# Replace a percentage of values in a column with another

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a tricky problem, maybe one of you can help.

I have a column with several distinct values, one of which is "Not Available". I would like to create a calculated column by replacing those "Not Available" values with 4 new values, say "Value 1", "Value 2", etc.. distributed equally i.e. 25% will be "Value 1", 25% will be "Value 2" etc. I really appreciate any help I can get. I should mention that my data lives in SSAS TDM so I can't use the query editor.

Thanks!

Below you will find some test data along with my desired results.

```
Example = 
DATATABLE (
    "Value", STRING,
    {
        { "Not Available" },
        { "Not Available" },
        { "Not Available" },
        { "Not Available" },
        { "Not Available" },
        { "Not Available" },
        { "Not Available" },
        { "Not Available" },
        { "Not Available" },
        { "Not Available" },
        { "Not Available" },
        { "Not Available" },
        { "Bike" },
        { "Bike" },
        { "Bike" },
        { "Bike" },
        { "Skateboard" },
        { "Skateboard" },
        { "Skateboard" },
        { "Skateboard" },
        { "Skateboard" },
        { "Skateboard" },
        { "Snowboard" },
        { "Snowboard" },
        { "Snowboard" },
        { "Snowboard" },
        { "Snowboard" },
        { "Snowboard" },
        { "Penny Board" },
        { "Penny Board" },
        { "Penny Board" },
        { "BMX" },
        { "BMX" },
        { "BMX" }
    }
)
```

Desired results:

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example table and the desired result?

Comment: @AlexisOlson please see my edit, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the other answer, I will assume you have an indexed replacement table. I will also assume you can create a unique index for your `Example` table (that's a separate question).

The logic is the same, but now as a DAX calculated column:

```
Value2 =
IF (
    Example[Value] = "Not Available",
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        'Replace'[Value],
        'Replace'[Index], MOD ( Example[Index], COUNTROWS ( 'Replace' ) )
    ),
    Example[Value]
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Wow, what an elegant solution. Tip of the hat to you buddy, that was illuminating. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to do this in the query editor since it's easier to create index columns there.

Make sure both your tables are loaded in the query editor, a replacement table, `Replace`.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows({{"Value1"},{"Value2"},{"Value3"},{"Value4"}},{"Value"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Value", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1)
in
    #"Added Index"
```

And your example table.

1. Add an index to your example table.
2. Transform the index column by taking the modulo by the row count of `Replace` (4 in this case).
3. Merge `Replace` onto `Example` matching on the index.
4. Expand the `Value` column to `Value.1`.
5. Add a custom column to choose which of these to use.
6. Clean up. Remove any columns you don't want to keep.

Here's the M code for the query:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W8ssvUXAsS8zMSUzKSVWK1RkuIk6Z2QQZwdmJJalJ+YlFKVTn5uWXU5sXkJqXV6ngRDTfyTcCk44FAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Value = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Value", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Calculated Modulo" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Index", each Number.Mod(_, Table.RowCount(Replace)), type number}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Calculated Modulo",{"Index"},Replace,{"Index"},"Replace",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Replace" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Replace", {"Value"}, {"Value.1"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Replace", "Value2", each if [Value] = "Not Available" then [Value.1] else [Value], type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index", "Value.1"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: I apologize I should've specified that I am using an SSAS TDM so I don't think I can use this.

Comment: If you've got a direct query, I don't think you can add a column at all.

Comment: I would be making these changes in ssas as a calculated column and referencing the new field.